# Implement Marker Interface in Spring WebServices

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern, marker-interfaces

I want to implement Marker interface, having two sub-class, something like factory pattern.

```
public interface TryMarker {
}
```

Bean 1 with all getters & setters & annotations

```
public class AadharLogs implements TryMarker{
    private AadharRequest req;
    private AadharResponse res;
}
```

Bean 2 with all getters & setters & annotations

```
public class PanLogs implements TryMarker{
    private List<PanRequest> req;
    private PanResponse res;
}
```

When I pass this JSON, I get the error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ds] in context with path [/automation] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.awcsoftware.dto.ekyc.TryMarker]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.awcsoftware.dto.ekyc.TryMarker` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.awcsoftware.dto.WorkItem["kycValidationLogs"]->java.lang.Object[][0]->com.awcsoftware.dto.ekyc.KYCValidationLogs["logs"])] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.awcsoftware.dto.ekyc.TryMarker` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.awcsoftware.dto.WorkItem["kycValidationLogs"]->java.lang.Object[][0]->com.awcsoftware.dto.ekyc.KYCValidationLogs["logs"])
```

Comment: This link might help you out: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception

Comment: During deserialization, Jackson must have a way of determining which concrete type of the interface to deserialize the data into. You will need to use [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/jackson-json-type-info-annotation.html) with one of the type resolution strategies and adjust your JSON accordingly

Comment: I can't change the JSON,  it's been finalized with the customer. I need something at service layer where we can downcast to our desired object and perform our operations